# Assessing Cannibalization, intervention of new mobile app on monthly sales

Tags: regression, time-series, spss, intervention-analysis

I am a beginner in statistics and looking for suggestions from you all on the approach for one of my study.

For my study, there is a company which sells products via its online website (lets call it Desktop Website). They have recently launched a mobile app in addition to the desktop website. Both online website & mobile app sell the same stuff.

**What I am try to understand:**

1) Whether sales through mobile app is cannibalizing sales through online website

2) Whether introduction of mobile app has led to increase in the total sales ( through both online website & mobile app)

**I have the following in my hand:**

1) Monthly sales data from 2011 Jan (to date ) for our Desktop Website

2) Monthly sales data from 2012 Sep (to date ) for our mobile app. The mobile app was launched only on Sept 2012

3) Page views on mobile & Desktop website for the aforementined respective dates.

Pakages: SPSS, Excel.

**General observations from the data:**

1) The  sales (for both mob & online) shows **annual seasonal effects** ( sales more during holiday months)

2) The  sales (for both mob & online) shows a **positive linear trend**.

**What I did:**

1) To understand intervention effect of the mobile apps on the desktop sales, I regressed the Desktop Website sales data with 11 seasonal dummies and an intervention dummy ( 0 for months before Sept 2012 and 1 otherwise)

*Results:* The R square was 67% (Adjusted R square =53%). But Durbin-Watson showed .789 which meant autocorrelation exists on the residual errors. So even though the intervention_dummy coefficient had highest value and with p value almost 0%, I had to reject the model because of the auto correlation.

2) In the next model, I included the mobile sales figures too. i.e  I regressed the Online sales data with Mobile sales data and 11 seasonal dummies ( Did not include intervention dummy because SPSS automatically removed it while running the analysis )

*Results*: R square = 95%, Adjusted Rsquare= 91%. Durbin-Watson = 2.17 &  the Regression Standardized Residual histogram shows almost a perfect normal distribution.  The coefficient for Mobile Sales figure was low and corresponding pValue was at 40%!. ***Does this mean that mobile sales is not impacting the desktop sales ?***. Can I safely conclude that cannibalization is not taking place?

What do yo suggest for assessing the impact of mobile app on the overall sales?

Preferably I am looking for something that can be done with help of statistical packages and less of heavy mathematical models if that's possible. But any suggestion is welcome as I think I have hit analysis paralysis!

Comment: I don't think you need 11 seasonal dummies. Also, make sure to check model diagnostic before making any conclusion.